# I couldnt find class library (.NET Core) in ASP.NET Core 6 project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, class-library

I tried to create a class library for .NET Core, but there is only .NET or .NET Standard library option

Comment: ".NET Core" is now called ".NET 5" and/or ".NET 6". There is no "Core" word anymore.

Comment: I Just started learning .net. In the tutorial video, there is create- new project- aspnet.core(mvc) and then add-new-class library(core) in solution explorer. For me it looks like new-class library(.net standard). Can I create with this option?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of what you see. Do you have any filters applied in the drop-down lists at the top?

Comment: https://ibb.co/YfQGgWG

Comment: The top result is what you want: "Class Library - a project for creating a class library that targets .NET or .NET Standard" (_do not_ select "Class Library (.NET Framework)" as that's not compatible with .NET Core nor .NET  5+).

Comment: The computer in the course and on my own computer looked different In Visual Studio, . I had also installed all the sdks and checked targets. So I was confused. There is no problem, on my computer it appears as class library(.Net), on the course it appears as a class library(core). When I look at it from Dependence, I understand what you mean. Thank you so much